# Make condition when one date is greater than the other in R

Tags: r

I would like to make a condition considering the dataset below. I believe that the `if` condition can be used, if not, it can be another way.

I would like to make a condition as follows:

If my chosen `date2` is greater than `date1` (`date1` will always be just a single date, as you can see in my `df datase`t) the calculation will be as follows: date2 - date1 + 1 = X -> this X will be the amount of DR columns that will be deleted from my `df dataset`.

I will present the code of my `df dataset` and then an example for you to see.

```
df <- structure(
  list(date1 = c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
       "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-04-02","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-03"),
       Week= c("Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Monday"),
       DR01_PV = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6), DR02_PV= c(4,2,6,7,3,2,7,4),DR03_PV = c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5),
       DR04_PV = c(5,4,3,3,6,2,1,9),DR05_PV = c(5,4,5,3,6,2,1,9),
       DR06_PV = c(2,4,3,3,5,6,7,8),DR07_PV = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

 df
   date1      date2       Week      DR01_PV DR02_PV DR03_PV DR04_PV DR05_PV DR06_PV DR07_PV
1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02   Friday       4       4       9       5       5       2       2
2 2021-06-28 2021-04-03 Saturday       1       2       5       4       4       4       5
3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08 Thursday       4       6       4       3       5       3       4
4 2021-06-28 2021-04-09   Friday       3       7       3       3       3       3       4
5 2021-06-28 2021-04-10 Saturday       3       3       3       6       6       5       9
6 2021-06-28 2021-07-01 Thursday       4       2       2       2       2       6       4
7 2021-06-28 2021-07-02   Friday       3       7       1       1       1       7       7
8 2021-06-28 2021-07-03   Monday       6       4       5       9       9       8       8
```

**Example:**

If I choose 01/07 (`date2`), which is a date greater than `date1` (28/06), we have the following:

date2 - date1 + 1 = X

01/07 - 28/06 + 1 = 3 + 1 = 4

This 4 means that the first 4 DR columns will be deleted from my `df dataset`, ie DR01_PV, DR02_PV, DR03_PV and DR04_PV. My new dataset (`df1`) will then be:

```
df1
       date1      date2     Week DR05_PV DR06_PV DR07_PV
1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02   Friday       5       2       2
2 2021-06-28 2021-04-03 Saturday       4       4       5
3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08 Thursday       5       3       4
4 2021-06-28 2021-04-09   Friday       3       3       4
5 2021-06-28 2021-04-10 Saturday       6       5       9
6 2021-06-28 2021-07-01 Thursday       2       6       4
7 2021-06-28 2021-07-02   Friday       1       7       7
8 2021-06-28 2021-07-03   Monday       9       8       8
```

If I choose 02/07 (`date2`), which is a date greater than `date1` (28/06), we have the following:

date2 - date1 + 1 = X

02/07 - 28/06 + 1 = 4 + 1 = 5

This 5 means that the first 5 DR columns will be deleted from my `df dataset`, ie DR01_PV, DR02_PV, DR03_PV, DR04_PV and DR05_PV. My new dataset (`df2`) will then be:

```
df2
       date1      date2     Week DR06_PV DR07_PV
1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02   Friday       2       2
2 2021-06-28 2021-04-03 Saturday       4       5
3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08 Thursday       3       4
4 2021-06-28 2021-04-09   Friday       3       4
5 2021-06-28 2021-04-10 Saturday       5       9
6 2021-06-28 2021-07-01 Thursday       6       4
7 2021-06-28 2021-07-02   Friday       7       7
8 2021-06-28 2021-07-03   Monday       8       8
```

I tried to insert exampl to be more understandable.

Every help is welcome!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can first convert the date columns to a date format with the `lubridate` library.

```
library(lubridate)
df[, 1:2] = lapply(df[, 1:2], FUN = as_date)
```

Then a helper function to calculate the value you are after.

```
get_cutoff = function(date) {
  date2 = as_date(date)
  date1 = df[1,1]
  as.numeric(date2 - date1 + 1)
}
```

I'm assuming you want to repeat this process, so I made a function to remove the appropriate columns. The argument `start_index` is whatever column it should start removing from since it seems it is not the first column. If the date happens to be greater than the first observation in the `date1` column, the original data frame is returned.

```
subset_data = function(date, start_index) {
  if (as_date(date) > df[1,1]) {
    end_index = start_index + get_cutoff(date) - 1
    return(df[, -c(start_index:end_index)])
  } else {
    return(df)
  }
}
```

You need to be aware of the format the date you give is, but with "2021-07-02" (and a starting column index of 4) this gives:

```
subset_data("2021-07-02", 4)

       date1      date2     Week DR06_PV DR07_PV
1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02   Friday       2       2
2 2021-06-28 2021-04-03 Saturday       4       5
3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08 Thursday       3       4
4 2021-06-28 2021-04-09   Friday       3       4
5 2021-06-28 2021-04-10 Saturday       5       9
6 2021-06-28 2021-07-01 Thursday       6       4
7 2021-06-28 2021-07-02   Friday       7       7
8 2021-06-28 2021-07-03   Monday       8       8
```

and a date of "2021-07-01" gives:

```
subset_data("2021-07-02", 4)

       date1      date2     Week DR05_PV DR06_PV DR07_PV
1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02   Friday       5       2       2
2 2021-06-28 2021-04-03 Saturday       4       4       5
3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08 Thursday       5       3       4
4 2021-06-28 2021-04-09   Friday       3       3       4
5 2021-06-28 2021-04-10 Saturday       6       5       9
6 2021-06-28 2021-07-01 Thursday       2       6       4
7 2021-06-28 2021-07-02   Friday       1       7       7
8 2021-06-28 2021-07-03   Monday       9       8       8
```

Functions can then be modified as appropriate to best fit your situation.

EDIT: If you also wish to filter the rows of the data based on the input date instead of just the columns you can modify the `subset_data` function. This uses the `filter()` function of the `dplyr` package.

```
subset_data = function(date, start_index) {
  date = as_date(date)
  if (date > df[1,1]) {
    end_index = start_index + get_cutoff(date) - 1
    df[, -c(start_index:end_index)] %>%
      filter(date2 == date)
  } else {
    return(df)
  }
}
```

Which gives:

```
> subset_data("2021-07-02", 4)
       date1      date2   Week DR06_PV DR07_PV
1 2021-06-28 2021-07-02 Friday       7       7
```

But will give the original data set if the value is less than the value in `date1` as per the requirement.

Comment: @ JSouza Answered here instead of other thread.

Comment: Thanks Cazman! That's exactly what I wanted. :)